# After Logout don't navigate to the page visited before

Tags: php, session

How to *create a session variable*, and once logout is successful no need to navigate to the page that is visited before.

The *Login.php and logout.php* pages are  provided below:

**Login.php**

```
require( 'dbConfig.php');

session_start();
$msg = "";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$name = $_POST["userid"];

if ($name == '' ) {
    $msg = "You must enter all fields";
}
else
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid = '$name' ";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    if ($query === false) {
        echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $name;
            header('Location: teams.php');
            exit;
    }

    $msg = "Username do not match";
}
}
?>
```

**Logout.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(session_destroy())
{
header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

**ISSUE :** After successful logout the page is navigating to the page visited before.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot really prevent the browser from trying to navigate back, since the content of the pages you gave out before the logout action is under the browsers control, specifically it can be cached. Then only thing you can do is to prevent the caching of payload by sending appropriate headers. You can google for examples for that.

Comment: You are using a deprecated version of `mysql`. Use `MySQLi` instead. See: http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

Comment: You have shown no signs of even bothering to research your own code before bringing it here. `header` is what causes a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

In your **logout.php** page, instead of `if` condition, simply write:

```
session_destroy();
```

So your page code would be :

```
<?php
session_start(); // not compulsory to write
session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: I have wrote this code,still i am facing same problem.i.e after logout browser back button navigating the previous pages.Please help me.Thanks in Advance.